# How to efficiently rename columns in Datasets (Spark 2.0)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

With DataFrames, one can simply rename columns by using `df.withColumnRename("oldName", "newName")`. In Datasets, since every field is typed and named, this doesn't seem possible. The only work around I can think of is to use `map` on the Dataset:

```
case class Orig(a: Int, b: Int)
case class OrigRenamed(a: Int, bNewName: Int)

val origDS = Seq(Orig(1,2), Orig(3,4)).toDS
origDS.show
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+

// To rename with map
val origRenamedDS = origDS.map{ case Orig(x,y) => OrigRenamed(x,y) }
origRenamed.show
+---+--------+
|  a|bNewName|
+---+--------+
|  1|       2|
|  3|       4|
+---+--------+
```

This seems a very round-about and inefficient way just to rename a column. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly more concise solution would be something like this:

```
origDS.toDF("a", "bNewName").as[OrigRenamed]
```

but in practice renaming is simply not meaningful on statically typed `Dataset`. While we use the same columnar representation as `Dataframe` (`Dataset[Row]`) semantics is completely different here.

Name of the column corresponds to a specific field of the stored objects so it is not something that can be dynamically renamed. In other words `Datasets` are not statically typed `DataFrames` but collections of objects.

Comment: I was trying to avoid descending into `Dataframe`, and use only the type-safe `Dataset` operations. But I see your point, thanks!

Comment: ok but what if you map a Dataset and the result is a dataset of, say Ints.  Now you have a Dataset of Ints and the column is named "value" but maybe you want to call it "myInt"

Answer (score 0):

You can make it slightly more concise, while maintaining semantics:

```
origDS.map(o => OrigRenamed(o.a, o.b)).show()
```